# Why do I have "category" in my permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

I added two category pages to a site I am working on and I found out the permalink in the url is wrong.

I set the permalink as `/%category%/%postname%` and I created two categories "News" and "Offers"

I was supposed to get `mydomain.com/news` or `mydomain.com/offers` (I created the category links using the built-in menu system) but I get this instead: `mydomain.com/category/news` and `mydomain.com/category/offers`

Why do I have "category" in the url? How can I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting your permalinks to `%category%/%postname%`, you are setting the permalinks *only for your posts and pages*.

Below the posts and pages permalinks option is another one for your categories. Just set your categories slug to `.` and it will just be the category name. Here's a visual example:

[image]

Comment: Best answer as it does not require a plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [WP No Category Base plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) to remove it.